# Merge data frames in R with partial match in common column, entries separated by semicolon

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidy

I'm trying to merge several data frames by an identifier column which contains strings (ids) separated by a semi-colon, and fill the values of the entries not found in the other data frame with NAs, and have a final common id based on the longest string (with more elements separated by a semicolon) present in the row.

The id is string with one or more elements separated by a semicolon. The strings might appear in different order in the other data frames, contain the same or more strings. I have looked around for similar questions and tried with `regex_inner_join` as well as followed posts using a fuzzy join or agrep type of join, but in my case the string "word" would always be the same, i.e. no miss-spellings. Is a protein ID so it should be the same, and what I have tried has not been successful or taking a lot of time. Each data frame contains around 5000 rows.

I have tried by adding an id and then separating the column identifiers, followed by merging, following the same steps on another data frame, and trying to remove duplicates of the id of each group. Merging to the original data frames and then rbind both data frames and make them "wide". However this is too cumbersome, and I also have not been successful in reaching a common merged data frame, nor the data frame that I'm looking for.

```
df1$id <- 1:nrow(df)
separate_rows(df, name, sep = ";")
```

bis for df2, and then

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, by = "name", all=TRUE)
```

As for the common id I have come up with

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(common = c_across(starts_with("name"))[which.max(nchar(c_across(starts_with("name"))))])
```

An example of the type of data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("a;b;c", "d", "k;p", "e;f", "g", "h;i"), value = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 2, 7))
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("b;c", "d;o", "e;f;z", "g;l", "x;y"), value = c(NA, 1, 5, 4, 5))
df3 <- ...
```

Expected result

| name.df1 | name.df2 | value.df1 | value.df2 | common |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a;b;c | b;c | 1 | NA | a;b;c |
| d | d;o | 2 | 1 | d;o |
| k;p | NA | 3 | NA | k;p |
| e;f | e;f;z | NA | 5 | e;f;z |
| g | g;l | 2 | 4 | g;l |
| h;i | NA | 7 | NA | h;i |
| NA | x;y | NA | 5 | x;y |

Ideally I would need a solution that can be expanded to more than 2 data frames.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you joining pairs of datasets at a time

Comment: Yes, pairs of dataset at a time would be more than fine

Comment: It's not really clear what you're merging on. For instance, if there was a `"k;d"` value in the "name" column in `df2`, would it merge with the second or third row of `df1`?

Comment: That would be an extreme case and although it might happen, I don't think it would be a large proportion. I could imagine that in case of duplicates one could have a set of rules: the entry with more "strings" would win (a;b;c;d over c;k). If there are the same "length" as in your example only the first to appear would be kept.